# Cloud Service with Web Role - Where is the website?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Beginner question. Here are some possibly relevant software versions:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- .NET Framework 4.5 and above
- Microsoft Azure Compute Emulator v2.7
- Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator v4.1
- Microsoft Azure SDK v2.7

I am following these steps (and ONLY these steps) to create a simple Cloud Service with a simple Web Role:

1. Open up Visual Studio.
2. Select FILE -> New -> Project
3. On New Project, select Azure Cloud Service and continue.
4. Add ASP.NET Web Role to the cloud service.
5. Select the MVC template for the Web Role.
6. Once the cloud service is created, press F5 to test my cloud service locally.

Here is my understanding of what pressing F5 does: it runs an instance of the cloud service (which contains a web role) in a local debugging environment. This is an emulated environment providing a simulated Cloud Service and a simulated Azure Storage service. When the debugging environment is launched, I should see a website running.

**So my question is, where is my website? Nothing pops up after pressing F5.**

If I right-click on the Compute Emulator, and click "Show Compute Emulator UI", I see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djbph.png

So obviously the WebRole is running. But I expect for my browser to pop up and display something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzO6p.png

I have verified that this happens to at least two other people running these exact same steps on different computers. Any ideas as to what obvious thing I must be missing?

I have already checked that on the WebRole properties, under Configuration, the Startup action is to launch browser for the http endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Party answering my own question. In the Compute Emulator, I see this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgHGu.png

So, going to my browser and typing in http://localhost:20431/ successfully pulls up my website.

I still do not know how to AUTOMATICALLY make the website open when the cloud service is run, but that is for another time.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Role gets deployed in emulator but the website should be deployed on your local dev box with IIS express. I don't think the emulator VM has IIS installed in it. That is why if you attempt to configure any IIS settings in Web Role's entry points it fails.